# Azure PowerShell: Is it possible to call bash commands from script written in ps1?

Tags: linux, bash, azure, azure-powershell

I created ps1 script, which creates a Linux VirtualMachine and opens ssh session with it. And I would like to ask if it is somehow possible to have bash commands already written in this script. I mean, if I call my script.ps1, it creates my virtual machine, opens ssh session and does e.g. all apt-gets and so on. Is it possible?

Comment: Seems like something you could easily test by creating a hello world script.  If you have figured out how to ssh  (which I didn't think was possible in PSH) then running "bash -c "ifconfig" from within a script should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is possible. Instead of that, i would recommend to do that using [command-line interface](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli-install/) which may be enabled in Bash. CLI is here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli

Bash in Windows (if you are going to use Windows) [is possible only in the latest Windows 10 builds](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2016/04/01/bash-for-windows-why-its-awesome-and-what-it-means-for-powershell/), so you will need to integrate that possibilities somehow